# Cannot catch "proxy block page" error with Invoke-RestMethod / Try Catch ignored

Tags: azure, powershell, try-catch, invoke-restmethod

I am utilising [Azure Instance Metadata Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service) API. This will only work on an Azure VM, which is fine, but I want some error handling. The trouble is that when I run this on my development laptop (heavily locked down environment), I get our corporate proxy block page and nothing I try (no pun intended) will catch the block page and thus handle the error.

It is like the proxy intercepts the request before `Invoke-RestMethod` can do anything.

Is there any way to catch the block message?

```
try
{
    $oRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -Method GET -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2020-06-01"
}
catch [System.Net.WebException]
{
    Throw "An error has occurred: $($_.exception.Message)"
}
```

`$oRequest` is empty and even piping to `Out-Null` doesn't stop the proxy block page message.

I appreciate this is really difficult to troubleshoot outside my corporate environment, but I am hoping someone may have experienced this behaviour and have a way of capturing the error.

The best I can come up with is a test to see if `$oRequest` is empty and handle that, but this doesn't seem right and it still shows the block message in the PS console.

PowerShell version 7

T. I. A

Comment: It's sounds like this error is a none terminating error. Try to use -ErrorAction Stop at your invoke-RestMethod command

Comment: Can you run Fiddler while your script is running and capture the request / response pair? That might shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason you're getting the error is because you're catching the original error, then forcing another to occur by using `throw`. You already caught it, no need to throw another error. You can't pipe a `throw` to `out-null` because there is nothing to send to the  pipeline.

Also, though it may not be necessary at all times, it's good practice to `-ErrorAction Stop` on cmdlets that you wish to catch errors for.

```
try
{
    #This is where the exception will be thrown
    $oRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -Method GET -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2020-06-01" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [System.Net.WebException] #this catches the error that was thrown above and applies it to the built-in variable $_ for the catch's scope
{
    #if you uncomment the throw line, notice how you don't reach the next line,
    #this is because it creates a terminating error, and it's not handled with a try/catch
    #throw "bananas"
    $banana = "An error has occurred: $($_.exception.Message)"
}
Write-Host $banana
```

Comment: Thank you. I honestly did try `-ErrorAction Stop`. Removing `[System.Net.WebException]` from `catch` fixed it. My fault for copying a colleague's code.